# JAVA - JTable using array strings. These arrays are in try{

Tags: java, mysql, merge, bind

The program have to download datas from MySQL database. and fill the JList.
I want to bind these datas.

Here you have a code:

```
        Connection connection = null;
        String dbtime;
        String query = "Select * FROM EMP";
        String[] celDatas = null;
        String[] celNames = null;
        try {

            (...)

            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            int NumOfCol = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            celNames = new String[NumOfCol];
            celDatas = new String[NumOfCol];

            for(int weq=1; weq<=NumOfCol; weq++) {
                System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(weq));
                celNames[weq] = rsmd.getColumnName(weq);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    dbtime = rs.getString(weq);
                    System.out.println(dbtime);
                    celDatas[weq] = dbtime;
                }
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }


    final JList source = new JList(celDatas,celNames);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(source);
    pane.setSize(f.getSize().width-60,300);
    pane.setLocation(30,20);
```

As you can see, these String Arrays are in try brackets, which can be a source of the problem.

When I compile my program, it shows:

```
at Application2.run(Application2.java:261)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:652)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Application2.java:261 is celNames[weq] = rsmd.getColumnName(weq);

How to resolve the problem?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Amen. Please clarify your problem.

Comment: The stacktrace seems incomplete. Also, why would there be a stacktrace when you compile?

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing `celNames[]` and `cellDatas[]` using `weq`, which iterates over values `1` through `NumOfCol` *inclusive*, while the arrays are of size `NumOfCol`, hence you're indexing them out of bounds.

Instead, index your arrays like this:

```
celNames[weq - 1]
celDatas[weq - 1]
```

Btw, by convention, variable names should start with a lowercase letter, so `NumOfCol` should be `numOfCol`.

Comment: But I have a problem with final JList source = new JList(celDatas,celNames);
It shows this problem in Netbeans: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8455739/Java-Problem.png

Comment: Yeah, that constructor doesn't exist, see [javax.swing.JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) for a list of valid constructors.